# Replace some text using SED and HEX

Tags: regex, sed, hex

I have a big text file with some ugly chars like

HeвЂ™s lean, heвЂ™s mean, heвЂ™s got a awesome flamethrower and jetpack вЂ“ whatвЂ™s not to love here?

I'd like to replace

вЂ™

to

'

to have "He's lean, he's mean" etc

but standard SED command

```
sed -i 's/вЂ™/'/g' file.txt
```

does not work.

Symbols вЂ™ has HexCode <0432><0402><2122> (looks like that)

I tried something like

```
sed -i 's/\x432\x402\x2122/'/g' file.txt
```

but nothing happenned

Thanks a lot for any ideas how to manage that.

Comment: Check the encoding of the input source. The garbage is most likely caused by wrong encoding.

Comment: I guess but I need to edit the file AS IS

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\o320\o262\o320\o202\o342\o204\o242/'\''/g' file
```

To get the octal representation use sed as so:

```
sed -n l0 file
```

and insert an `o` infont of `\xxx` strings (`\oxxx`).

Comment: +1, I didn't know this feature to get the octal representation.

Answer (score 1):

You can't include a single quote in single quotes. Use double-quotes:

```
sed "s/вЂ™/'/g" file.txt
```

Comment: I tried sed -i "s/вЂ™/'/g" - no reaction, nothing changed

Comment: Okay, You can try to find the hex codes in file.txt with `hexcode -C file.txt | less`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like

```
sed -n '1!H;1h
$ {s/.*/вЂ™/;G
:a
   s/^\(...\)\(\n.*\)\1/\1\2'/
   t a
   s/^....//p
   }' YourFile
```